# Domain and mail redirect

Tags: email, domain, redirect, hosting

I have domain at providerA and hosting with domain at providerB.

I configured DNS that domainA would redirect to hostingB. With .htaccess setup so now entering either domainA or domainB it shows website hosted at providerB and url shows as domainA in browser.

But now my mail that is sent to emails with domainA also redirects to email accounts with domainB.

What should I do, so email sent to lets say user@domainA.com would get it and not user@domainB.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your DNS settings, set a `MX` record for domainA like so:

```
domainA. MX 10 mailserver.domainA.
```

then,

```
mailserver.domainA. A 1.2.3.4
```

That will set up `mailserver.domainA` as your mail server and mails sent to `user@domainA` will be recieved by that server.

Not sure if this answer might help you as you didn't provide much info but this is a possible answer.